# How to match the values from the field according to the procedure and then write each pair to a new line?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to work with a matrix and assign 2 values ​​to each other in a row. I assign each pair to a new line. I assign pairs from the bottom of the matrix. The first pair is the first number from the penultimate line and the last number from the last line. The second is the number one line up with the second number in the line below. Then again the first number from the same line with the third number in the last line. And go through all the numbers in this way. This is better seen in the examples below

example 1

```
13 14 15
22 23 24
31 32 33
```

It is better to see the number assignment in this matrix for understanding
First I assign 22 to 23. Then I go to the next column and start assigning from the first number to the last. So I connect 13 to the line with 23, then 13 with 33 and then 23 with 33 and so I proceed to the end of the matrix

```
      13 14 15
   22 23 24
31 32 33

22 32
13 23
13 33
23 33
14 24
```

example 2

```
14 15 16 17 18
23 24 25 26 27
32 33 34 35 36
41 42 43 44 45
```

The same is true for this matrix. First I assign 32 and 42, then 23 and 33, 23 and 43, 33 and 43 etc ...

```
         14 15 16 17 18
      23 24 25 26 27
   32 33 34 35 36
41 42 43 44 45



32 42
23 33
23 43
33 43
14 24
14 34
14 44
24 34
24 44
34 44
15 25
15 35
15 45
25 35
25 45
35 45
16 26
16 36
26 36
17 27
```

If you ask how to get to this form of matrix so

imagine a matrix

```
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
```

I determine the number of values ​​in the line -n
number of columns - b

the formula is

```
n-b + 1 = 5-3 + 1 = 3
```

Result 3 is the specified number of values ​​in each row

result from the formula

```
      13 14 15
   22 23 24
31 32 33
```

but I have already solved this modification of the matrix. I only showed this to bring the situation closer and to understand.

I tried to assign numbers diagonally, but my attempt only works with a 4x3 matrix
You can see that in my experiment

my attempt

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

a=np.array([[13,14,15,16,17,18],
            [22,23,24,25,26,27],
            [31,32,33,34,35,36]])

x = np.transpose(np.triu_indices(a.shape[0],1))
y = x + np.arange(-1,a.shape[1]-1)[:,None,None]

# assign edge values
y[0] = y[1][0]
y[-1] = y[-2][-1]
print(a[x,y].reshape(-1,2)[2:-2])
```

result

```
[[22 32]
 [13 23]
 [13 33]
 [23 33]
 [14 24]
 [14 34]
 [24 34]
 [15 25]
 [15 35]
 [25 35]
 [16 26]
 [16 36]
 [26 36]
 [17 27]]
```

For array of a different size, it throws me a array size error

```
a=np.array([[14,15,16,17,18,19],
            [23,24,25,26,27,28],
            [32,33,34,35,36,37],
            [41,42,43,44,45,46]])
```

result

```
IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this to make it a more comprehensive solution for all matrix sizes and generalize?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at result again basically we are taking a `diagonal` and finding all `2 number selection combination`.
Take your `last array` example and take any diagonal like taken in photo you will get the above logic

[image]

**CODE :**

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

a=np.array([[14,15,16,17,18,19],
            [23,24,25,26,27,28],
            [32,33,34,35,36,37],
            [41,42,43,44,45,46]])

l = []
shape_ = a.shape
for i in range(2-shape_[0], shape_[1] ):
    l += list(combinations(np.diag(a, i), 2))

for i in l:
    print(i)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
(32, 42)
(23, 33)
(23, 43)
(33, 43)
(14, 24)
(14, 34)
(14, 44)
(24, 34)
(24, 44)
(34, 44)
(15, 25)
(15, 35)
(15, 45)
(25, 35)
(25, 45)
(35, 45)
(16, 26)
(16, 36)
(16, 46)
(26, 36)
(26, 46)
(36, 46)
(17, 27)
(17, 37)
(27, 37)
(18, 28)
```